Testing public methods that modify private properties
To be clear i am not asking how or if i should test private methods.
Setup.

CQRS pattern.
DDD write model aggregate with complex business rules etc.
All properties are private.
Aggregate is mapped to some ORM via reflection so no unecessary public getters.

Scenario
I imagine some public method like publish() that has a state transition, and i then want to assert that the private state property is the particular state that it should be.
Considered options
One way to do this is have public getters for all properties, use these getters in tests, as well as to help facilitate the mapping instead of using reflection, but then i need all these unecessary public getters.
Second option is down stream testing. I update the aggregate, persist it, and check the value was persisted in the data store or by retrieving some view model. But then i can't test the aggregate in isolation.
Current consclusion
So at this stage i have either

Public getters that serve no relation to the business logic
Can't test the aggregate in isolation

Are there better solutions i am not thinking of?

Observer.
Whether that's "better" than your other alternatives is a matter of trade offs.
Observer can be justified a number of different ways.  Perhaps it's "logging", perhaps it's "telemetry", perhaps its something subscribing to "domain events"... but the core interaction of interest to us is this: that under some circumstance that the test can control, the "aggregate" sends the information we want to some other object that our test can interrogate.
Whether or not this is "better" than your other alternatives depends on your context: which particular benefits you are trying to realize by "testing", and how you value the different trade offs.
(For example, if you are developer responsible for creating automated inconsistency detectors to run after each refactoring, you are likely to be interested in properties that are different from those of interest to a tester who is trying to ensure that shipping the product doesn't inevitably lead to lawsuits and the incarceration of the CEO.)

At a high level, your aggregate is exposing operations (commands) and using its state to decide whether each operation is valid/allowed/acceptable.
This suggests that your tests can be expressed as:

put the aggregate into some state (by definition, any reachable state for the aggregate comes from a sequence of operations; as a shortcut you might allow a direct way to set the state, but there are drawbacks to that)
execute the operation under test
assert that some other operation(s) (allowing the aggregate under test to "branch" can be helpful here) are accepted/rejected

This maps well to the "Given-When-Then" style of specifying behavior.  If you can't come up with an operation whose acceptance/rejection depends on a given field, that's a really strong sign that the field doesn't belong in that aggregate.
